# Show telephone symbol in Calendar when using arbitrary video conferencing tools

Tags: calendar, ical

Due to the current situation I'm using a lot of video conferencing software to meet with other people.

I organise my daily schedule using Apple Calendar Version 11.0 and noticed that when I'm using a Zoom link as the location for an event, a nice telephone symbol appears. When clicking on it I get redirected to the said link and can conveniently open Zoom.

[image]

However, when I use less popular video conferencing tools (e.g. https://bigbluebutton.org/) this doesn't work.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the same behaviour for less popular tools as for e.g. Zoom?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can control easily is be sure the links to your meetings are attached to the event.

This very handy interface came to my attention using Fantastical and it’s super useful, and I’m also waiting for first party support of some handy conference apps.

- https://flexibits.com/fantastical

I’m not smart enough (yet) to figure how to format other links that Apple doesn’t now detect, but know you could try another calendar while everyone figures out the exact mechanism to influence this if the vendor apps don’t get updated to claim their links in a manner Apple can connect the event to the helper app.

Here’s the list of what apps fantastical can detect:

- https://flexibits.com/fantastical#conference-calls-section